# Apache Lucene for Static Website

Tags: lucene, search-engine, custom-search-provider

Is it possible to use  Apache Lucene for Static websites ?
If not, what other alternatives are available excluding Google CSE ?

Comment: Please, add some more details on what exactly is the thing that you wish to do

Comment: It should create and maintain index of website and should provide search results on same site. Just like Google Custom Search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly reasonable to use Lucene on a static website, if you can execute the Lucene search code on the server. If you can't execute any server code, as far as I know you need to look elsewhere than Lucene.

Comment: Can i host code on google appengine and run website on some different server ? It would be great if you could provide link to instructions to achieve same. Thanks a lot.